# Непонятное двойное увеличение счётчика

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, task

Имеется ситуация, при которой создается впечатление, будто функция выполняется 2 раза, но, по факту получается что 2 раза в ней только увеличивается определенный счётчик. Почему такое происходит мне не совсем понятно. Приведу блоки кода, которые могут быть косвенно связаны с этой функцией. Код немного упрощу, убрав явно неважные моменты.

**Функция в которой происходит увеличение счетчика дважды:**

```
    void SendedBlock(int counter, int counter2)
    {
        PMData _sendData = new PMData(pmd);
        //.....

        // Добавляет указанную функцию в пул задач(опишу его в кратце далее)
        // И именно в передаваемой функции счётчик уменьшается соответвенно
        PoolForAction.Add(FuncAction, _sendData);
        // Следующая строка увеличивается 2 раза, но не сразу
        SendedCounter++;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

**Функция в которой вычитается счетчик:**

```
    void FuncAction(object _params)
    {
        if (_params is MyType)
        {
            //......

            //Вот тут счетчик вычитается но только 1 раз(далее объясню последовательность)
            SendedCounter--;
        }
    }
```

**Задача в которой вызывается выполнение этой функции:**

```
    MultyLevelSended MLS = new MultyLevelSended();
    void TaskStart()
    {
        SendedCounter = 0;

        MLS.LVL1CancelToken = LocalCancelToken;
        MLS.LVL2CancelToken = SendedCancelToken.ToArray();
        MLS.LVL1Count = Counts;
        MLS.AUpdate = i =>
        {
           /// Некая функция в которой я проверяю нужно ли входить на второй уровень цикла.
        };
        MLS.Run(SendedBlock);
    }
```

**MultyLevelSended:** (просто обертка некая, может она и играет роль)

```
public class MultyLevelSended
{
    public int LVL1Count = 0;
    public int LVL2Count = 0;
    public CancellationTokenSource LVL1CancelToken = null;
    public CancellationTokenSource[] LVL2CancelToken = null;
    public Action<int> AUpdate = null;

   public void Run(Action<int,int> _aMain)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < LVL1Count; i++)
                {
                    AUpdate?.Invoke(i);
                    try
                    {
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < LVL2Count; j++)
                            {
                                _aMain?.Invoke(i,j);
                            }
                        }, LVL2CancelToken[i].Token).Wait();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }, LVL1CancelToken.Token).Wait();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

`PoolForAction.Add()` по сути просто вызывает функцию `Post()` для `Dataflow` блока, собственно в котором все отправленные функции выполняются по очереди.

Так вот. Запуская функцию `TaskStart` (Которая ранее вызывается через `Task.Run` как задача) счётчик обнуляется. далее заполняются все нужные моменты для обертки цикла и собственно он запускается на выполнение. Предположим что главная передаваемая функция выполнится 2 раза (второй уровень счётчика будет равен 2м). Он выполнится 1 раз, соответсвенно 1 раз увеличив счетчик и отправив в Пул функцию которая её уменьшит на 1 при выполнении, так же произойдет и второй раз. Но после чего (ориентируясь по точкам остановы) он вернется к `SendedCounter++` и просто 2 раза подряд его увеличит. По логике если он увеличиавет второй раз, то он и второй раз должен отправить событие в пул для выполнения, и счётчик должен уменьшиться, но он этого не делает, а лишь увеличивает 2ды счётчик. В чём проблема понять мне так и не удалось. Буду благодарен за помощь.

**UPD:**
Немного дополнил обертку для теста, дабы после выхода из цикла вызываемая функция становилась `Null` и не выполнялась:

```
try
{
     test = _aMain;

     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < LVL2Count; j++)
         {
              test?.Invoke(i,j);
         }
         test = null;
      }, LVL2CancelToken[i].Token).Wait();
}
catch { }
```

Но и это не помогает. Код доходит до `test=null`, после чего возврашается обратно к `test?.Invoke(i,j);` и всеравно она выполняется, ибо она опять не равна `null`

**UPD 2:**

Поменял код и убрал из него задачи, и написал так:

```
    public void Run(Action<int, int> _aMain)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LVL1Count; i++)
        {

            if (!LVL1CancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (AUpdate?.Invoke(i) ?? true)
                for (int j = 0; j < LVL2Count; j++)
                {
                    if (!LVL2CancelToken[i].IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Прохождения внутреннего цикла " + j + " Внешний " + i);
                        _aMain?.Invoke(i, j);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Дабы проверить причину проблемы. Но и в том и этом случае, схема остаётся такая же, дважды вызывается функция, причём уже со следующим индексом. Наглядно как происходит это всё я изобразил в этом изображении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как описано выше, этот "проскок" появляется только если запускать **без отладки**, если запустить и пошагово проходить проверять, то в 98% случаев этих 2х лишних вызовов не будет.

Comment: Я не C# программист но у вас SendedCounter это что переменная или параметр класса? и только в одной функции он(она) инкрементиться?

Comment: @Naumov SendedCounter это локальная переменная в классе. Да. только в одной. Все именения в указанных функциях

Comment: У вас сложный код, однако. Я бы предложил временно превратить `SendedCounter` в свойство, тогда можно будет поставить breakpoint на сеттере, и вы увидите, кто его меняет во второй раз.

Comment: @VladD я поставил вывод в консоль когда происходи вход в функцию увеличения и функцию уменьшения. По сути получилось что реально происходит в какой то момент двойной вход в функцию увеличения, но при этом функция с уменьшением толи не доставляется в пул, толи по какой то причине игнорируется, но опять же суть в том, что по какой то причине функция вызывается дважды и не подряд, а вызывается она только в цикле `MultyLevelSended`. Я на основе лога составил примерно такую последовательность. [Скрин](http://cs630918.vk.me/v630918173/272db/B3zrstZJwRI.jpg)

Comment: @VladD эти 2 вызова функции происходят очень странно. То есть смотря по этой схеме, которую я написал, `AUpdate` "даёт добро" на вход на второй уровень цикла для элемента с индексом **1**. после чего, по очереди вызывает в цикле главную функцию(`_aMain`), после чего, ещё до выхода из этого цикла, главная функция вызывается ещё 2 раза, но уже для элемента с индексом **2**, то есть ещё до проверки через  `AUpdate` и до изменения счётчика, а точнее сразу же после выполнения первых 2х.

Comment: жуть какая то. Сплошные StartNew..Wait. Зачем вообще таски?!

Comment: @vitidev Ради отмены всего кода через токен.

Comment: @BwehaaFox так токен не прервет код внутри задачи, а всего лишь пометит задачу как отмененную. Для выхода по отмене нужно в коде проверять token,IsCancellationRequested (или вариант с Throw).

Comment: @vitidev  при отмене токена выскакивает исключение в Задаче. что её прерывает. Суть проблемы даже не в отмене.

Comment: @BwehaaFox высключение выскакивает только когда доходит до любого .Wait. Суть проблемы в конкурентном доступе из-за потоков. У вас потоки даже там где это вообще не надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ответ найден:**
По сути данная проблема возникала даже не из за рассинхронизаци потоков или из за чего-то такого. Вся суть была в ином куске кода.

**По порядку:**
У меня для выполнения неких задач использовался `TransformBlock` из `TPL Dataflow`. Имелась функция добавления задачи в очередь, но в последствии мне потребовалось сделать аналогичную функцию, которая останавливала поток в котором вызывается, пока отправленный блок кода не выполниться, то есть некое ожидание.

Изначально функции имели следующий вид (примерно):

```
public void Add(Action<object> func, PMData data)
{
    ActionParams _pack = new ActionParams();
    /// всякие инициализации
    ActionBlock.Post(_pack);
    ActionAddedEvent?.Invoke(_pack);
}

public void AddWithAwait(Action<object> func, PMData data)
{
    ulong AwaitIndex = _poolIndex + 1;
    Add(func, data);
    while (ActionBlock.Receive() != AwaitIndex)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

В целом это работало, но проблема "Вторичного фантомного" вызова функции, как я понял, лежало на плечах `ActionBlock.Receive()` в случае если в блоке пула и в блоке отправки задачи в пул, стояло идентичное ожидание. В моем случае пул обрабатывался с задержкой 2 секунды, и блоки отправлялись с такой же задержкой, что возможно заставляло выполнять ожидающий блок толи дважды, толи как то ещё, ещё до его повторного вызова и каким то образом проскакивалась проверка через функцию. Так же заметил, что такая проблема возникала только во время Рантайм выполнения без брикпоинтов и без пошагового выполнения. Поменяв код на следующий, проблема решилась.

```
    public void Add(Action<object> func, PMData data)
    {
        ActionParams _pack = new ActionParams();
        ActionBlock.Post(_pack);
        AwaitebleTotalIndex++;
        ActionAddedEvent?.Invoke(_pack);
    }

    public void AddWithAwait(Action<object> func, PMData data)
    {
        Add(func, data);
        ulong AwaitIndex = AwaitebleTotalIndex;
        while (_poolIndex<AwaitIndex)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если это многопоточный код, стоит использовать Mutex.
И самый простой путь понять, как увеличивается, поставить брекпоинт и по стектрейсу увидеть вызов.